# How to set a proxy for apt-cyg?

Tags: windows, linux, proxy, cygwin

How to set a proxy for apt-cyg, http and socks?
i tried using

```
export http_proxy=
```

but it did not work.

Comment: +1 for bringing apt-cyg to my attention

Comment: I don't know cygwin, but have you tried proxychains or tsocks? Have you tried adding proxy settings in wgetrc that apt-cyg should use? If the nature of apt-cyg is just bash, you might be able to hack it.

Answer (score 9):

This should work :

```
export ftp_proxy=http://[user]:[passwd]@[proxy.foo.com]:[portnumber]
```

Comment: This is an approppriate answer as of today. `apt-cyg` uses ftp to download packages.

Comment: Not anymore I guess, I was trying to install busybox and it only worked when I added/exported http/https proxies. @Kosiek

Answer (score 3):

You can also add it all in one line (it works well with cygwin/apt-get embedded in mobaxterm - add it to .bashrc):

```
export {ftp,http,https}_proxy=http://[user]:[passwd]@[proxy.foo.com]:[port]
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about Cygwin, but these are the lines from my ~/.bashrc

```
export http_proxy=http://[user]:[passwd]@[proxy.foo.com]:[portnumber]
export https_proxy=http://[user]:[passwd]@[proxy.foo.com]:[portnumber]
export HTTP_PROXY=http://[user]:[passwd]@[proxy.foo.com]:[portnumber]
export HTTPS_PROXY=http://[user]:[passwd]@[proxy.foo.com]:[portnumber]
```

If cygwin is similar to bash, it should work.

Comment: Works on Windows Subsystem for Linux (pointing to CNTLM proxy)

Answer (score 1):

I made it work by setting two Windows environment variables: http_proxy and http_proxy.  I previously had HTTP_PROXY, but that wasn't picked up.

Note that as Cygwin is a Windows process, after setting the new environment variables you need to launch a new Cygwin process to pick up the change.

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but none of the answers seem right.

From what I can tell trying to UNSET a proxy to run this on one of my boxes, I was getting this error: wget: unable to resolve host address ‘webproxystatic-mywork.com’

Looks like apt-cyg uses wget.  So this brings you to this question: [setting proxy in wget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11211705/setting-proxy-in-wget)

The answer of which is:
set (or in my case unset) `http_proxy`/`https_proxy` in `/etc/wgetrc`:

```
# You can set the default proxies for Wget to use for http, https, and ftp.
# They will override the value in the environment.
#https_proxy = http://proxy.yoyodyne.com:18023/
#http_proxy = http://proxy.yoyodyne.com:18023/
#ftp_proxy = http://proxy.yoyodyne.com:18023/

# If you do not want to use proxy at all, set this to off.
#use_proxy = on
```