# How can I set a proxy for Wget?

Tags: linux, proxy, wget

I want to download something with Wget using a proxy:

```
HTTP Proxy: 127.0.0.1
Port: 8080
```

The proxy does not need a username and password.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 552):

For all users of the system via the `/etc/wgetrc` or for the user only with the `~/.wgetrc` file:

```
use_proxy=yes
http_proxy=127.0.0.1:8080
https_proxy=127.0.0.1:8080
```

or via `-e` options placed after the URL:

```
wget ... -e use_proxy=yes -e http_proxy=127.0.0.1:8080 ...
```

Comment: My wget says it must be `use_proxy=on`, not `use_proxy=yes`. Works well otherwise.

Comment: Checked. It works with wget -e <http_proxy>=127.0.0.01:8080 <http://download>..., omitting the "use_proxy=yes" command parameter. Thanks!

Comment: @Thomas Jensen You are right the [wgetrc-manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Wgetrc-Commands.html) states that it should be `on` or `off`, but actually trying a bogus command: `-e use_proxy=bnw` gives `wget: use_proxy: Invalid boolean ‘bnw’; use 'on' or 'off'.` while `=yes` gives no such error, so it seems to be inofficially allowed.

Comment: `http_proxy=http://<user>:<password>@127.0.01:8080` and likewise. otherwise you might have to feed these explicitly while calling the wget (refer - https://askubuntu.com/a/429943/350255)

Comment: How do I turn it off?

Comment: @Tessaracter : `wget --no-proxy`

Answer (score 105):

Type on the command line:

```
export http_proxy=http://proxy_host:proxy_port
```

For an authenticated proxy,

```
export http_proxy=http://username:password@proxy_host:proxy_port
```

And then run

```
wget fileurl
```

For https, just use https_proxy instead of http_proxy. You could also put these lines in your [~/.bashrc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)#Legacy-compatible_Bash_startup_example) file, so that you don't need to execute this every time.

Comment: How to remove the proxy

Comment: $ unset http_proxy

Comment: experimentally found that needed to use lower case, not upper case

`$ wget --version
GNU Wget 1.14 built on linux-gnu.

+digest +https +ipv6 +iri +large-file +nls +ntlm +opie +ssl/openssl`

Answer (score 46):

The following possible configurations are located in `/etc/wgetrc`. Just uncomment and use it...

```
# You can set the default proxies for Wget to use for http, https, and ftp.
# They will override the value in the environment.
#https_proxy = http://proxy.yoyodyne.com:18023/
#http_proxy = http://proxy.yoyodyne.com:18023/
#ftp_proxy = http://proxy.yoyodyne.com:18023/

# If you do not want to use proxy at all, set this to off.
#use_proxy = on
```

Answer (score 22):

Wget uses environment variables. Something like this at the command line can work:

```
export http_proxy=http://your_ip_proxy:port/
export https_proxy=$http_proxy
export ftp_proxy=$http_proxy
export dns_proxy=$http_proxy
export rsync_proxy=$http_proxy
export no_proxy="localhost,127.0.0.1,localaddress,.localdomain.com"
```

Answer (score 19):

After trying many tutorials to configure my [Ubuntu 16.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_16.04_LTS_.28Xenial_Xerus.29) LTS (Xenial Xerus) system behind an authenticated proxy, it worked with these steps:

Edit `/etc/wgetrc`:

```
sudo nano /etc/wgetrc
```

Uncomment these lines:

```
#https_proxy = http://proxy.yoyodyne.com:18023/
#http_proxy = http://proxy.yoyodyne.com:18023/
#ftp_proxy = http://proxy.yoyodyne.com:18023/
#use_proxy = on
```

Change `http://proxy.yoyodyne.com:18023/` to `http://username:password@domain:port/`

***Important***: If it still doesn't work, check if your password has special characters, such as `#`, `@`, ... If this is the case, escape them (for example, replace `passw@rd` with `passw%40rd`).

Answer (score 12):

If you need to execute wget just once with the proxy, the easiest way is to do it with a one-liner like this:

```
http_proxy=http://username:password@proxy_host:proxy_port wget http://fileurl
```

or with an https target URL:

```
https_proxy=http://username:password@proxy_host:proxy_port wget https://fileurl
```

Answer (score 6):

In [Debian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian) Linux, wget can be configured to use a proxy both via environment variables and via *wgetrc*. In both cases, the variable names to be used for HTTP and HTTPS connections are

```
http_proxy=hostname_or_IP:portNumber
https_proxy=hostname_or_IP:portNumber
```

Note that the file */etc/wgetrc* takes precedence over the environment variables, hence if your system has a proxy configured there and you try to use the environment variables, they would not seem to have any effect!

Answer (score 5):

In my Ubuntu installation, the following lines in $HOME/.wgetrc did the trick!

> http_proxy = http://uname:passwd@proxy.blah.com:8080
>
> use_proxy = on

Answer (score 5):

Use

```
export http_proxy=http://proxy_host:proxy_port/
export https_proxy=https://proxy_host:proxy_port/
```

or

```
export http_proxy=http://username:password@proxy_host:proxy_port/
export https_proxy=https://username:password@proxy_host:proxy_port/
```

As all others explained here, these environment variables help to pass on proxies.

**Note:** But please note that if the password contains any special character then that needs to be configured as `%<hex_value_of_special_char>`.

**Example:** If the password is `pass#123`, it needs to be used as `pass%23123` in the above export commands.

Answer (score 5):

Add below line(s) in file **~/.wgetrc** or **/etc/wgetrc** (create the file if it is not there):

```
http_proxy = http://[Proxy_Server]:[port]
https_proxy = http://[Proxy_Server]:[port]
ftp_proxy = http://[Proxy_Server]:[port]
```

For more information, https://www.thegeekdiary.com/how-to-use-wget-to-download-file-via-proxy/

Answer (score 4):

Start Wget through a [SOCKS5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOCKS#SOCKS5) proxy using **tsocks**:

1. install tsocks: `sudo apt install tsocks`
2. configure tsocks

   As root:

   ```
   vi /etc/tsocks.conf
   ```

   Add:

   ```
   server = 127.0.0.1
   server_type = 5
   server_port = 1080
   ```
3. start: `tsocks wget http://url_to_get`

Comment: *SOCKS server is not on a local subnet!
failed: Connection refused.*

Comment: wget: unable to resolve host address ‘google.com’

Answer (score 2):

In Windows - for Fiddler say - using environment variables:

```
set http_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:8888
set https_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:8888
```