# Installing PostgreSQL 9.4: "gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found"

Tags: postgresql, debian, gnupg, postgresql-9.4

I'm trying to install PostgreSQL 9.4 on a clean, new Debian Jessie machine.

I'm following these instructions: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Apt#Quickstart

When I get to this point:

```
wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | apt-key add -
```

I get this error:

```
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Split that command and verify what you're getting is the actual key and not some connection error.

Comment: Side note: Debian Jessie already ships PostgreSQL 9.4, do you really need to build on your own? Testing/unstable usually ship very bleeding edge versions, these might be a better way to go instead of building on your own (updates included).

Comment: @JensErat thanks. I ended up just using `apt` to install it, much easier!

Comment: yep but in Jessie you have 9.4 (and magnificiant JSONB type so you can apt-get remove mongodb !), but still miss 9.5 (and it's more than welcome UPSERT capabilities !)

Answer (score 2):

These instructions are fine, you must suffer from connection problems (or get other contents served than expected. Do following:

- Run `wget -o - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc` (without `--quiet` and without pipe to GnuPG) to inspect what's actually happening. Is `wget` indicating any connection problems?
- You can also download the file from your browsers, simply store the textual contents using copy-paste to a text file and import it using `apt-key add [path-to-file]` (or, given somebody finding this question wants to import to the default GnuPG keyring, `gpg --import < [path-to-file]`).

Most likely `wget` does not find the root certificated referenced by the PostgreSQL website, you're behind some proxy which is [not configured for `wget`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11211705/695343) or a gateway changing the website; at least the results returned are not key data in a format GnuPG expects.

Comment: This is a good answer. Running wget without --quiet and without the pipe to GnuPG will show more details on the issue, and wget will often suggest a solution (eg: --no-check-certificate)

Answer (score 2):

In my case the problem was caused by an incorrect https certificate from postgresql.

Just add the  --no-check-certificate to the wget command.

Comment: If you disable `wget`'s certificate validation, a man in the middle attacker might not only send you with a manipulated PostgreSQL package (and other system packages!), but also provide a seemingly valid certificate. If fetching from HTTPs is your only trust anchor, do at least not disable certificate checks without understanding why they failed.