# Install logstash-output-couchbase behind a proxy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, proxy, rubygems, logstash, couchbase

I'm trying to install the output-couchbase gem into logstash but the proxy is refusing to download the gem.

I've googled possible solutions to this problem and it seems that the best way to download and install a gem when behind a proxy is like this:

```
gem install --http-proxy http://user:password@proxy:port $gem_name
```

I assume this works when installing a gem for ruby.

is there a way to insert proxy settings when trying to download a gem into logstash?

ive attempted the following in the bin folder of my logstash installation:

```
logstash-plugin install --http-proxy http://user:password@proxy:port $gem_name
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I update Ruby Gems from behind a Proxy (ISA-NTLM)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4418/how-do-i-update-ruby-gems-from-behind-a-proxy-isa-ntlm)

Answer (score 0):

You can use wget to download the gem and then use the offline plugin installation (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/offline-plugins.html#_install_or_update_a_local_plugin).

To use a proxy with wget: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11211812/6113627