# How to use no_proxy on Linux machines - wildcards, leading dots

Tags: proxy

I am puzzled by the `no_proxy` environment variable on Linux.

There are many instructions on the internet that show leading dots for example `.localdomain.com` https://stackoverflow.com/a/19719875/202576

```
export no_proxy="localhost,127.0.0.1,localaddress,.localdomain.com"
```

This example is used in relation to using `wget`. I can't however confirm that this works. For example on Ubuntu 18.04 I have remove the leading dot to get it to work. Note I am using a sub domain for example `wget mysite.localdomain.com`.

```
export no_proxy="localhost,127.0.0.1,localaddress,localdomain.com"
```

When I use a `curl` it will work with a leading dot.

So it seems that the way `no_proxy` should be configured depends on the tool? It is different for `curl` and `wget`.

Is there a convention for `no_proxy` that will work for all tools?

I suppose writing out each and every full domain name will work.

Answer (score 6):

There is no standard, that I'm aware of, so what you need to set/use depends on the implementation of the tool you use. Curl will work with a leading dot as it strips it whereas wget won't work (doesn't strip it).

Read some detailed analysis at https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2021/01/27/we-need-to-talk-no-proxy/:

Excerpt from that article:

> However, if there is a leading . in the no_proxy setting, the behavior
> varies. For example, curl and wget behave differently. curl will
> always strip the leading . and match against a domain suffix. This
> call bypasses the proxy:
>
> ```sh
> $ env https_proxy=http://non.existent/ no_proxy=.gitlab.com curl https://gitlab.com
> <html><body>You are being <a> href="https://about.gitlab.com/">redirected</a>.</body></html>
> ```
>
> However, wget does not strip the leading . and performs an exact
> string match against a hostname. As a result, wget attempts to use a
> proxy if a top-level domain is used:
>
> ````sh
> $ env https_proxy=http://non.existent/ no_proxy=.gitlab.com wget https://gitlab.com
> Resolving non.existent (non.existent)... failed: Name or service not known.
> wget: unable to resolve host address 'non.existent' ```
> ````

Answer (score -1):

We can go with this solution :

```
export no_proxy="localhost"
```